# Scikit-Learn Linear Regression on Square Matrix Seems Incorrect

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am linearly regressing `k` response variables `y` onto on `k` x `n` predictor variables `X`, where k >= n.  Using Scikit-Learn, the regression seems correct, except when `n = k`; i.e., when the matrix of predictors is square.  Consider the following MWE, where I randomly generate the matrix `X` and coefficients `b` to construct the `y`, then perform regression using scikit-learn to check that the coefficients are the same as the true coefficients:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model


n = 5  # number of predictor variables                                  
k = 5  # number of response variables, >= n *** Set = n for issue ***   
mu_b = 2.0  # mean of each component of b, used to create coeffs        

print "n = ", n

# generate true coefficients ~ N(2,0.09)                                
b = np.random.normal(2.0, 0.3, n)

print "b = ", b

# generate true predictors ~ N(0,25)                                    
X = np.random.normal(0.0, 5.0, (k,n))

# generate true target variables                                        
y = X.dot(b)


# create linear regression object                                       
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# train model                                                           
regr.fit(X,y)

# print coeffs                                                          
print "estimated b = ", regr.coef_

# print difference                                                      
print "difference = ", np.linalg.norm(b - regr.coef_)
```

If k > n there is no difference modulo machine precision, but when k = n there can be quite a difference.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Is this a known bug?

Comment: I think you're getting your concepts mixed up, in your code it looks like `k` is the number of predictor variables, and `n` is the sample size; and you need to have `n` strictly greater than `k` for the regression to make sense. Think about it, image you `k=1` so you just have one variable you're trying to predict, i.e. you're trying to calculate the gradient of a line. You'll need at least two points to caluclate this, so you must have `n>2`.

Comment: @maxymoo no, the code it correct. It works when I solve the system uses lstsq from np.linalg for a square matrix, and for k >= n using scikit-learn. I believe there is a bug in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the attribute `fit_intercept` of the `LinearRegression` class is set to `True`. This appears to have two effects. First, before the model is fitted using `linalg.lstsq`, the matrices, `X` and `y`, are centered by subtracting the mean in the `_center_data` method. Second, after the model is fit, the `_set_intercept` sets:

```
regr.intercept_ = y_mean - np.dot(X_mean, regr.coef_.T)
```

It is not clear from the documentation how this intercept term is derived.

In your case, you can inspect that in cases where `k > n` the resulting `intercept_` term is on the order of `1e-14`, but for `k = n`, `intercept_` is non-zero, explaining why coefficient vector mismatch in the case of `k = n`. You can remedy all this by simply setting `fit_intercept=False` in your model.

**Caveat**: a more meaningful answer, of course, might explain how the intercept term is derived, as well as provide insight as to why the intercept term is zero for `k > n`.